# Typoscript - Splitting "media" and "imagecaption" simultaneously

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I have made a plugin where I store many images in the "media" field and jsut as many captions in the field "imagecaption".

Now my wish is to display it like this:

```
image1.png
caption 1
image2.png
caption 2
image3.png
caption 3
```

This is how ive been trying to do it, but its not working:

```
plugin.tx_myplugin_pi1 = COA
plugin.tx_myplugin_pi1{
    10 = TEXT
    10.field = header
    10.wrap = <h1>|</h1>

    20 = COA
    20{
        10 = TEXT
        10{
            field = media
            split{
                token = ,
                cObjNum = 1
                1.current = 1
            }
        }

        20 = TEXT
        20{
            field = imagecaption
            split{
                token.char = 10
                cObjNum = 1
                1.current = 1
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But its not really working, as it shows first all the filenames and then the caption.

How could I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Split is a function which returns all elements. Within 20.10 you get the content of field image, splitted by an newline f.e. and after that, you get the content of 20.20 which has the imagecaption.

What you need to do (untested):

```
    10 = TEXT
    10{
        field = media
        split{
            token = ,
            cObjNum = 1
            1.current = 1
            # for each image, add the imagecaption
            1.append = TEXT
            1.append {
               field = imagecaption
               # split saves the index in REGISTER:SPLIT_COUNT
               listNum.stdWrap.data = REGISTER:SPLIT_COUNT
               listNum.splitChar = 10
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Looks almost what I want! But "splitchar.char = 10" is false. The right command is "splitchar = 10". And the "listNum.data" line isnt working :S

Comment: Figured it out! Its "listNum.stdWrap.data = REGISTER:SPLIT_COUNT"!! Thank you!!!!

Comment: What does "cObjNum = 1" and "1.current = 1" mean?

Comment: cObjNum = 1 || 2  optionsplit: the first would be renderd with definition 1, the second with definition 2. And you can use stdWrap there, what means select different renderings depending on an flag. F.e. you could use cObjNum.field = section_frame (or cObjNum.stdWrap.field  - untested;)  and then define an special rendering for each rendering.

Answer (score 2):

I do not think that token = \n is correct. You properly need to use .char = 10.
Also you will need to nest your TS somehow, because the current solution does handle the fields one by one.

Comment: Exactly. Is that "somehow" that I dont know.

Answer (score 0):

I can't remember at the moment but I've wrote an extension that adds a frame to a picture and caption. It can solve your problem with the captions: http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/ch_imgtext_renderengine/current/.

Comment: This is just a simple version of my problem. I dont want to use it like that.